# mwlib.rl / mwlib fonts

Tags: python, mediawiki

For a long time I'm trying to change the default serif font in mwlib / mwlib.rl

Unfortunately setting a font in fontconfig.py

```
{    'name': 'Arial',
    'code_points': ['Basic Latin',],
    'xl_scripts': ['Latin'],
    'file_names': ['freefont/Arial.ttf', ],
}
```

and

in customconfig.py respectively pdfstyles.py doesn't change the default Times font

```
######### FONT CONFIG
serif_font =  "Arial"
sans_font = "Arial"
mono_font = "FreeMono"
default_font = 'Arial'
```

The fonts are in the right directory.

Does someone know with which version this feature works?
I'm using mwlib 0.15.15 and mwlib.rl 0.14.6 
I have tried it with multiple different fonts as well as the FreeSans font.
There is no error but the font is not changing

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it... (on debian wheezy)

I started the following procedure in the directory

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/
```

I deleted everything in the above mentioned directory in my already running configuration (made backups as well) and I used the guide here:

http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/Mediawiki_collection_extension_installation

5.1 Prerequisites

Python
Cython

```
apt-get install cython
```

5.2 Installing mwlib

Before installing, you might edit mwlib/tagext.py around line 100 a tag to exclude extensions tags used and that can't be handled by mwlib, e.g. at some point I had to exclue manually: 'pageby', 'uml', 'graphviz', 'categorytree', 'summary' (but since sometimes end of 2009 this is fixed).

```
  sudo aptitude install make g++ perl python python-dev python-setuptools python-imaging re2c
   sudo aptitude install git-core
   git clone git://github.com/pediapress/mwlib
   cd mwlib

   sudo python setup.py build
   sudo python setup.py install
```

5.3 Install mwlib.rl

(with a variant in procedure, i.e. we create a new directory where git will put the files)

```
   git clone git://github.com/pediapress/mwlib.rl mwlib.rl.new
   cd mwlib.rl.new
   sudo python setup.py build install
```

Install the source code formatting package from http://pygments.org/ (debian packet: python-pygments)

```
   sudo aptitude install python-pygments
```

Install extra fonts

```
  sudo aptitude install ttf-indic-fonts ttf-unfonts ttf-farsiweb ttf-arphic-uming ttf-gfs-artemisia ttf-sil-ezra ttf-thai-arundina linux-libertine
```

In file `fontconfig.py`

```
 font_paths = [os.path.dirname(mwlib.fonts.__file__),
              os.path.expanduser('~/mwlibfonts/')
             ]
```

This under the assumption that the fonts are in the directory mwlib.rl.hg/mwlib/fonts or ~/mwlibfonts/ of the user that installs or root if you install as root.

Check what it can render - **FreeSans should appear...**

```
 mw-render --list-writers
```

You then can configure the mediawiki extension accordingly
5.4 Install tables of contents for mwlib.rl

```
 apt-get install pdftk
```

This will produce a visible TOC in the beginning of the book if installed (nothing else to do, mwlib.rl will detect this library). So far this TOC does not have hyperlinks (but users can open the bookmarks to the left in order to navigate)

After that I had to find the correct directory in which I had to put the customconfig.py:

```
find . -name \fontconfig.py
```

it returned

```
./mwlib/mwlib.rl.new/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mwlib/rl/fontconfig.py
./mwlib/mwlib.rl.new/mwlib/rl/fontconfig.py
./dist-packages/mwlib.rl-0.14.6-py2.7.egg/mwlib/rl/fontconfig.py
```

after only changing

```
 serif_font =  "FreeSans"
```

in

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mwlib.rl-0.14.6-py2.7.egg/mwlib/rl/pdfstyles.py
```

all the fonts where switched to FreeSans

Maybe there is a better way as I'm not a python specialist yet